# Conditional: "are not" vs. "don't be"

Tags: conditional-constructions, auxiliary-verbs, negation

Consider the following phrases (someone is talking with a friend who is challenging some mobsters):

> 1. If you ***are not*** careful, they will catch you.

or

> 2. If you ***don't be*** careful, they will catch you.

Is the second option acceptable or usual?
Are they both in according with grammar rules?

Comment: Yes, both versions are fine and standard English. In your 1st version, the verb "are" is an auxiliary BE (e.g. "If you aren't careful …"). In your 2nd version, the verb "be" is a lexical verb--but there are constraints on where the lexical BE can be used. (*CGEL* page 114, "Lexical be")

Comment: @F.E. Glad you left that comment. A question for you now that you've all gone an opened that can of worms in my head. Is *BE* lexical in "If you're careful"? Do you reckon ... ? (cuz I'm cnfoozed) :)

Comment: @Araucaria Lexical BE has only one shape: "be". It is used as a plain form; and for some speakers, it can also be used for present tense except for 3rd singular. So, that means that *"If you're careful …"* is auxiliary BE.

Comment: @F.E. If that be the case, how do we know that 2. there isn't a subjunctive *BE*, or that 2. isn't an alternative negative form of 1 - because *DO* necessitates a plain form anyhow? (did you see what I did there with that protasis?)

Comment: @F.E. Am just being troublesome ( - ish), because I have no-one to talk to right now :D Am going to hit the hay. Am working in 5 hours .. :)

Comment: @F.E. Cross posting ... but did you see what I did with that protasis, before I delete my last couple of comments? EDIT but might do a question in my lunchbreak  tomorrow ...

Comment: @F.E. Will see if I get the chance tomorrow- but I'm done for today. Happy NFLing!

Comment: @Araucaria Errrrrr-rrr! I'm thinking of maybe actually writing an answer post on this topic of lexical "BE" usage (and an associated nonstandard dialect), just to put down a straightened out layout of what I think is all involved, as I've got a good bunch of comments in my margins of CGEL.

Comment: @F.E. Yes, do!! I look forward to reading it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Consider the following phrases (someone is talking with a friend who is challenging some mobsters):
>
> 1. If you ***are not*** careful, they will catch you.
> 2. If you ***don't be*** careful, they will catch you.
>
> Is the second option acceptable or usual? Are they both in according with grammar rules?

SHORT VERSION: As to whether or not both versions are acceptable, the answer is:

- ***Yes,*** *both versions are grammatical and are considered to be standard English.*

In your 1st version, the verb "are" is an auxiliary BE being used in a typical copular usage (usage similar to "If you aren't careful …"). In your 2nd version, the verb "be" is behaving as a lexical ***be***--but there are constraints on where the lexical ***be*** usage can be used.

This explanation is based on my interpretation of the info that is in the 2002 *CGEL*.

---

---

LONG VERSION:

Your version #1 ("are not") might be considered to be slightly more formal of a style than a version that uses ***"aren't"***:

- 1.a If you ***are not*** careful, they will catch you. -- (original #1)
- 1.b If you ***aren't*** careful, they will catch you.

Both #1a and #1b are using the auxiliary verb "BE" where the verb "BE" is being used as a ***copular*** verb. And both versions are fine.

---

As to your version #2 ("don't be"), the verb "BE" is behaving as a ***lexical*** verb, taking *do*-support in a present-tense negative construction:

- 2. If you ***don't be*** careful, they will catch you. -- (original #2)

Some background info: *CGEL* considers there to be six main uses of the verb lexeme BE. In *CGEL* page 113:

> 2.5.7 ***Be***
>
> We distinguish the following uses of ***be***:
>
> [62]
>
> - i. *She **was** a lawyer.* -- [ copula ***be***]
> - ii. *She **was** sleeping peacefully.* -- [ progressive ***be***]
> - iii *They **were** seen by the security guard.* -- [ passive ***be***]
> - iv. *You **are** not to tell anyone.* -- [ quasi-modal ***be***]
> - v. *She has **been** to Paris twice already.* -- [ motional ***be***]
> - vi. *Why don't you **be** more tolerant?* -- [ lexical ***be***]

Your version #2 is similar to [62.vi ], which involves a *lexical **be*** usage.

In *CGEL* page 114 has info related to lexical ***be*** usage, including examples:

> Lexical ***be***
>
> This is found with *why* + ***do*** and with *if*:
>
> [63]
>
> - i.a. *Why **don't** you **be** more tolerant?*
> - i.b. *Why **doesn't** he **be** more tolerant?*
> - ii.a. *If you **don't be** quick you'll lose.*
> - ii.b. *If he **doesn't be** quick he'll lose.*
> - iii.a. **<sup>%</sup>** *If you **be** quick you'll win.* -- (grammatical in some dialects only)
> - iii.b. ***** *If he **be / bes** quick he'll win.* -- (ungrammatical)

Their discussion of [63] is:

> The *why* construction [i ] is virtually restricted to the negative: **<sup>?</sup>** *Why do you be so intolerant?* is at best very marginal. Pragmatically [i ] conveys "You/He should be more tolerant" and thus bears some resemblance to the imperative, but syntactically it is quite distinct from the imperative construction by virtue of having a present tense form, not a plain form. This is evident from the person-number contrast between *don't* in [i.a] and *doesn't* in [i.b], for imperatives with a 3rd person singular subject do not differ in verb-form from those with a 2nd person subject (cf. *Somebody **open** the door, please*).
>
> The same person-number contrast is seen in the conditional construction [ii / iii ], which again conveys that you/he should be quick (in order to win / avoid losing). This time, however, some speakers allow *be* in the positive, but with no corresponding 3rd person singular form.

With additional info:

> Two points about ***be*** follow from the data of [63]. The first is that in these constructions it behaves as a lexical verb, taking ***do***-support in present tense negatives. The second is that for speakers who use construction [iii.a] the lexical and auxiliary uses correspond to different lexemes, for the inflectional forms are different. Lexical ***be*** has only the one realisational form *be*, but it realizes either the plain form (when taking ***do***-support) or (in positive conditionals) a present tense form, distinct from the *are* that we have with auxiliary ***be***.

---

What the above *CGEL* info means is that, with respect to the lexical ***be*** usage, there are two dialects of standard English: Dialect A, Dialect B.

**DIALECT A:** The speakers of this dialect consider only the unmarked examples in [63], which are the four examples in [63.i-ii ], to be grammatical:

- i.a. *Why **don't** you **be** more tolerant?*
- i.b. *Why **doesn't** he **be** more tolerant?*
- ii.a. *If you **don't be** quick you'll lose.*
- ii.b. *If he **doesn't be** quick he'll lose.*

The examples are all negatives and used under the constraint of being in constructions involving "*why* + ***do***" or" *if*". The examples are using the auxiliary verb lexeme "BE".

These speakers do not accept [iii.a], which is ungrammatical to them: **<sup>*</sup>** *If you **be** quick you'll win.*

**DIALECT B:** The speakers of this dialect accept the four examples in [63.i-ii ] that the Dialect A speakers accept, and also accept example [iii.a ] as grammatical, which is now unmarked:

- iii.a. *If you **be** quick you'll win.*

The reason why this example is not acceptable for Dialect A speakers is because it is not a negative.

Dialect B speakers consider **all** the lexical ***be*** usages to be using a different verb lexeme, which is a lexical "BE" verb lexeme, and it is different from the auxiliary "BE" lexeme. That is, they have two different verb lexemes, while Dialect A speakers have only the one standard auxiliary "BE" lexeme.

The reason why Dialect B speakers consider that the lexical ***be*** usage to be using a different verb lexeme -- the lexical "BE" verb lexeme -- is because it has its own present tense verb form: "be". For instance, the lexical "BE" lexeme's 2nd person form is ***"be",*** while the auxiliary "BE" lexeme's 2nd person is ***"are".***

This lexical "BE" lexeme is rather defective in that it only has a plain form and present tense form, and even the present tense form is defective in that it has no 3rd person singular form.

**NON-STANDARD DIALECT:** As to example [63.iii.b], it is ungrammatical for standard English. This is why it is marked with "**<sup>*</sup>**":

- iii.b ***** *If he **be / bes** quick you'll win.*

Notice that the example ("he be/bes") uses 3rd person singular, which is not acceptable for either Dialect A or Dialect B speakers.

---

ASIDE: Note that for many speakers, there is a non-standard alternate for [63.ii.b] in informal or colloquial style:

- 63.ii.b. *If he **doesn't be** quick he'll lose.* -- (standard, *CGEL*)
- alternate: **!** *If he **don't be** quick he'll lose.* -- (non-standard)

And also, as to [63.iii.b], there is a non-standard alternate for some speakers:

- 63.iii.b. ***** *If he **be / bes** quick he'll win.* -- (ungrammatical, *CGEL*)
- alternate: **!** *If he **be** quick he'll win.* -- (non-standard)

---

Note that *CGEL* is the 2002 reference grammar by Huddleston and Pullum et al., *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*.

Comment: +1 nice post. One question for now. What kind of BE is this?: "*Be an idiot like that again and I'll fire you*".

Comment: Oh just in case I can tempt you, or fancy adding a comment. [look here!](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/217760/what-is-the-difference-between-a-part-of-speech-and-a-function?noredirect=1#comment464027_217760)

Comment: @Araucaria I think that according to *CGEL*, a standard auxiliary verb BE, its plain form heading an imperative clause in a construction having a semantic meaning of a conditional. Oh, interestingly, this brings up a longer topic: Could some unusual, or not-fully-standard, "subjunctive" uses of BE actually be Dialect B's use of the lexical BE lexeme? -- But didn't want to try looking into that one, not this year. :)

Comment: @Araucaria Yeah, I glanced at that thread. EL&U is not a place for serious grammar discussion, or for accurate grammar opinions.

Comment: Your comment above aside, any chance with a reopen, upvote helping-hand [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/218058/parts-of-speech-and-functions-bob-made-a-book-collector-happy-the-other-day)? As you'll see, it's a basic job that needs doing by someone ...

Comment: @Araucaria Done! :D -- But I don't know why you're trying to teach them grammar, like, ya can lead a horse to water but ya cannot make it drink, ya know that one, right? Like, ya know, that place over there has gotten worse during and since the last moderator elections. Them high-rep-SWR-users don't like their grammar ignorance exposed like you're doing, them gonna hate you bad! :D Now I go and amuse me-self by browsing that thread--Reading them folks opinions, that make me feel sooooo smart and knowledgable on grammar!

Comment: @Araucaria Hey, that last EL&U question of yours is an easy one! (I remember one other of yours, where the responders didn't even realize they were being puzzled by [a direct object](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/203364/subject-of-asking-in-sent-a-letter-asking).)

Comment: @Araucaria Oh, I just read this ["chat"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19924/discussion-on-question-by-araucaria-parts-of-speech-and-functions-bob-made-a-b) session. What's that term for not being able to know what one doesn't know? A college textbook 101 English grammar would be useful to, er, many. I was going to say 101 English syntax, but I am finding that many linguists, especially famous ones, more so those that are famous generative linguists, still conflate traditional grammar, such as P.O.S., with today's English grammar.

Comment: @Araucaria And I'll try to not make any comments over there, such as *"Obviously each one of those are nouns or noun phrases!"* :D

Comment: Oh, come on! One for the road. Just a straight-forward answer ;) Otherwise I'm going to have to get the beeferfan involved and that will be the death of me! :D OK seriously, here's why: there are folks who are going to come onto the site and don't have anywhere else to go.What are they going to read? What kind of help is going to be given to them. What are they going to believe? (Just eat this mushroom, it'll be ok ...) If ELU really gets that bad so that no grammar questions are allowed, what will happen after they pull the plug with ELY to ELL?

Comment: @Araucaria What Wikipedia article? What question?

Comment: The one, erm, [here, where one might just have commented](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/218058/parts-of-speech-and-functions-bob-made-a-book-collector-happy-the-other-day) :D

Comment: @Araucaria I merely glanced over that wikipeida page on [noun adjuncts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct). Er, why would you want to even touch that nonsense. Lordy. Just let it lie and let it die, yup. :D

Comment: @Araucaria This here thread [Passive voice of intransitive verbs](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/218206/passive-voice-of-intransitive-verbs) is gonna be promising a whole bunch of merriment for all! :D -- Ah upvoted that question, too!

Comment: @Araucaria Check this out, [Ian McEwan's usage of “must” as a simple past](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/218177/ian-mcewans-usage-of-must-as-a-simple-past#comment465048_218180)! Ah knew modals were defective lexemes, but, er, a modal auxiliary not having any primary forms? Wow. Lordy. Do you think any dissenting opinions will be made?

Comment: Hope the NFL was a good showdown! Thanks for the edit, reopen, etc, etc ;) I'm afraid Tchrist started having a go at me (again) the other day and I refused to take it, so now he's close voting all my questions and down-voting all my posts - getting them onto the close-vote circular - :-) I  guess he was real embarrassed about me explaining the difference between a phonetic and phonemic transcription. He doesn't know the difference between those either ...

Comment: @Araucaria Well that guy is the same guy that tried to pass the 1985 Quirk et al. off as the 2002 *CGEL*. I doubt he has hardcopies of those two reference grammars, since one has a green cover while the other a red one, and their layout and fonts are quite different. And so, it makes one wonder . . . -- Hey, you're lucky that the moderators haven't deleted your dissenting opinions! :D

Comment: @Araucaria Lookie, lookie! I'm [contributing](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/218498/use-of-subjunctive-in-britain-vs-north-america#comment465757_218498)  over at EL&U! b but it does seem to be a waste of time. :D

Comment: Yes, I know, that's true. But I can't let it go just yet. I kind of enjoy the theatre of embarrassment. Also, I'm waiting for Tchrist to do something  as his normal aggressive self but get noticed while he's doing it so that he gets kicked off ELU. Also, the "top" answer to [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/what-exactly-is-an-adverb) has got to be stopped as a reason for closing questions before I quit the site ... if it kills me :) [maybe it will!]

Comment: Did you set that link up for me?

Comment: @Araucaria Er, that "top" answer only has two downvotes, and one of them is mine. That "top" answer post is pure nonsense, yet it is so typical for EL&U--that's why that site is beyond hope. Yes, that subjunctive thread was kinda for you. It has the usual bad info that is to be expected over there. You've been a member for 7 months now, eh? Ya remember a conversation we had some months ago, about 6 months being a usual length of time before one gets all fed up? :) I'm watching NFL playoffs and doing some grammar reading during the commercial breaks.

Comment: Erm, the other might be from me ... I think it was 4 months you said ... but I was only on three months in and I was already depressed. I'm reading George Orwell and having a traditional Irish stout. I wish I knew something about the NFL playoffs so I could make somekinda witty remark thing, but I don't! Hope it goes well, if you're rooting for someone special in particular!

Comment: @Araucaria When you have time, will you glance at this [deleted post](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/45980/8758) of mine, to see if the "for" could/should be interpreted as a preposition? My brain is mostly wiped out from reading some generative grammar stuff.

Comment: Not if you're H&P! :) Although, it has been argued that the case has not been fully made about *for* not being a preposition/sub conj in this case (i.e. it's been argued - can't remember where - that not enough has been said to clearly demonstrate why certain subordinators have been retained/included in the class. Indeed my first PhD proposal was about exactly that issue - and the status of infinitival *to*.

Comment: There are two other preposition *for* s, but that one ain't one of them. Btw, aside, have you ever noticed that this use of *to* is very prepositiony?

Comment: @Araucaria I think there are sometimes where there can be a pair of "PP + to-infinitival", and perhaps/maybe? that PP can be headed by a "for" preposition. I wanted to make sure that the OP's 3 examples weren't like that. Though, in the OP's examples (e.g. #3), that "for" expression sure does seem to have a lot of extra meaning (like a preposition "for"?) when interpreted as part of that example.

Comment: @Araucaria In the OP's #3 example, both the "for" and the "to" seem to have a lot of the prepositions' meanings. I'm not sure if that is partly due to the passive form, and/or the specific matrix clause.

Comment: Agreed, a bit like *to* when it seems to be used with a similar meaning as *in order to* ... Will double-check the third example, but I don't have H&P with me today! I see we're cross posting:)

Comment: @Araucaria Would it be better if I undeleted that post and we put our comments in over there? Or just do the comments as we are doing?

Comment: I don't think you need worry about this *for* being prepositional. I'd undelete your post for sure, if I was you:) Perhaps copy some obs over there and delete the others? But try out comments here in the first instance where the people is civilised.

Comment: @Araucaria Okay, maybe, er … My main concern about "for" being a preposition is the parse: "FOR [ NP + *to*-infinitive]", for #3. That's not possible, or not possible here in #3, is it? I don't want to stumble into a well-known sort of syntactical issue--and get egg all over my face! :)

Comment: I'm pretty confident, but on the other hand if you're feeling unsure, I ever so slightly less confident. Let me check it out when I get home - am still at college at the mo

Comment: @Araucaria I'm watching your "Bob made a book collector happy the other day" thread, and I'm sorta thinking of opening an ELL thread related to: P.O.S. and syntactic functions and semantic roles -- and maybe use your example sentence as my example! What ya think?

Comment: I think that would be something like *I did it for James to be happy*, or *I bought it for Bob to clean the house with*, no?

Comment: @Araucaria But can those two examples of yours have that "For X" be preposed (as done in #3)? And in your 2 examples, they would still be "For"-to-infinitivals, yes?

Comment: @Araucaria w.r.t. new ELL question thread: I was thinking of addressing all 3 issues, because the labels of those three topics get conflated together, and a rather simple example might make somethings clearer. E.g. "Bob" is a noun phrase (category) that realizes subject function (syntactic function) that plays the role of agent (semantic role) in the relation *made(bob, collector, happy).*

Comment: @Araucaria Identifying the actual role label isn't so important here; what's important is separating the semantic role label, whatever it is, from the other labels used for category and function. For instance, many conflate "subject" with the role of "agent", and end up calling an oblique NP as the "true subject" of a passive, e.g. "The ball was thrown by [the mailman]" with "the mailman" as the so-called 'true subject' though it is the agent.

Comment: Ok, sounds good to me! Rushing off to get a bus. Ciao

Comment: Have you got the details of that post where someone mentioned above might have been blathering rubbish about CGEL and CaGEL - I need to stick that stuff under his comment: ***Nobody but nobody has ever once claimed that a multiword phrase is an adverb. It is sad to see people made to waste their time tilting at strawmills*** Btw, don't reckon I'm going to get round to reading H&P tonight, not with that question (bit taxing at this hour ...). But will do tomorrow, promise.

Comment: Oh and do you have any thought about [this answer I did](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39807/difference-between-without-and-with-no/219998#219998). I got a down-vote from said person (getting a couple a day, minimum - ha!). But wondering if I stuffed something up because of the second vote ...

Comment: @Araucaria I had given you an up vote on that one! :) -- EL&U is cliquish, and some older members most likely have extra accounts. Anyhow, when I saw your first down vote, I had assumed that it was because you resurrected an old thread. And now, seeing your 2nd down vote, that might be from your "friend" or from one of his minions. Hey, that's EL&U, if you aren't pissing them off, then you're not doing something right (w.r.t. grammar).

Comment: @Araucaria Here it is, that [phony 2002 CGEL excerpt](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/181220/as-to-verb-vs-to-verb/181223#comment376521_181223). Remember to look at an older version of the guy's answer.

Comment: Oh shucks, can't go to bed just yet then :D Got some comedy reading to do!

Comment: @Araucaria Here the guy makes an [answer post](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/108067/prepositional-phrases/108072#108072), where the OP had already basically described the answer in her question--and she was probably asking for more of an explanation.

Comment: @Araucaria *Apparently Messrs. Huddleston and Pullam have decided to reclassify subordinating conjunctions as prepositions when their argument is a non-finite verb clause but leave them as conjunctions when followed by a finite clause. Makes no sense to me, but this would hardly be the first time I’ve caught Pullam barking up the wrong tree.* <== That is [one](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/181223/57102) of his many most hilarious stuff that he does! And he ain't even aware of it when he continuously do it! :D

Comment: EDIT: response to previous: Yes, I think so. Unfortunately, that's the kind of brusque, unfriendly, curt, verging on poisonous, arse-paralysingly tedious attitude that I expect in this case - sadly.

Comment: I've already wet myself twice and spewed wine all over the table laughing that :D  And I'm keeping lots of that in a file for posterity - or in his case posteriority. Oh geez I definitely need to go to bed ... - Hey, let me off for the lame humour, it's 4.30 am over here. Ciao, but feel free to leave any comments/gems on here to cheer me up on the long slog into work tomorrow! :)

Comment: @Araucaria Oh, I just notice this: *people will always bitch* -- which he wrote in his [edit](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/181223/revisions) history. He sure is a sorry excuse! :D

Comment: Re your preposition concerns in your other post, I can't find the relevant part in CaGEL. Doesn't help that there's so many *for* s kicking about! You don't know the relevant section(s) do you?

Comment: @Araucaria I think that somewhere in there they give an example of a "PP + to-infinitival" where the 'for-PP' isn't the subject of the to-infinitival (but I'm not sure if they did), but I couldn't quickly find it the other day when I was looking for it. (Maybe in the adjunct chapter?) But I'm too busy with this generative grammar stuff at the moment. :)

Answer (score 6):

I googled a bit and it seems that this sentence is considered more "formal":

> If you **are** not careful, they will catch you.

The second sentence is grammatical, but is considered somehow less "formal" and is used more often in speech, less often in "formal" writing:

> If you don't **be** careful, they will catch you.

**Are** and **be** are forms of the verb **to be**, which has eight forms in all: *be, being, been, am, is, are, were, was.* This is the most diverse verb in the English language. "Be" is its basic form.

Why "don't be careful" is not so "formal", despite being used in speech often?

One [discussion](http://www.onestopenglish.com/support/ask-the-experts/grammar-questions/grammar-the-verb-to-be/146357.article), at OneStopEnglish, mentions this use. It says that in imperative sentences - when we command someone to do or not to do something - we use the verbs **do** and **don't** to support the verb **be**:

> **Do be** seated; **Don’t be** stupid.

But in the indicative sentences - when we do not command someone but merely describe something - we don't use **do** to help **be**:

> I **don't be** stupid. (! this sentence is wrong)
>   I **am not** stupid. (this sentence is okay: the same verb "to do", but now, without the support of the auxiliary verb "don't", it can assume the form **am** that agrees with the first-person pronoun **I**.)

But this use of **don't** to help **be** (as in "don't be stupid") overflows into if-clauses in spoken language:

> If you **don’t be** quiet, I’ll send you to your room! ("non-standard" sentence used in spoken language)
>   If you **aren't** quiet, I'll send you to your room! ("standard" sentence)

Could this "spoken-language" construction be used in all cases? I guess not. Imagine a customer saying to a car dealer:

> If this car **doesn't be** blue, I will not pay you. (sounds weird to me)
>   If this car **is not** blue, I will not pay you. (sounds better)

---

Reference: [CGEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cambridge_Grammar_of_the_English_Language), page 113, "the six uses of **be**" (a short excerpt [at the Language Log](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/myl/languagelog/archives/003002.html))

Comment: +1, but I'm not sure it's exactly true that "don't be" in non-imperatives is extended from its use in imperatives. Rather, I think that it's some varieties of English restrict "lexical" uses of *be* (the sense of *be* found in "don't be silly" or "he's being silly") to the imperative/infinitive/subjective *be* and the gerund/participle *being*, whereas others allow it to be used as a more-or-less regular verb. Varieties of the latter type will accept "If you don't be careful", or (from a movie preview I once saw) "What do we do?" "We be ourselves."

Comment: +1 I think the key difference between *If this car don't be blue* and *If you don't be careful* is that these are really two different *BEs*. *BE blue* is the ordinary copular use of *BE*, attributing a quality to the subject. *BE careful* is the 'behavioral' use of *BE*, the one we find with *BE* in the progressive, meaning *BEHAVE*. "John's a jerk" is copular: it means that's the kind of guy  John is. "John is being a jerk* is behavioral: it means that's how John is behaving right now. The imperative is, I think, always behavioral.

Comment: There is lack of numerical agreement in _car don't_.  You should write _If this car doesn't be blue_, for a fair comparison with _If this car is not blue_.

Comment: @StoneyB you got the point, they sound a little different to me because of these two "meanings" of BE. In some languages we can have two variations of BE. The BE like a permanent state or the BE like a moment state. The "are not" sounds like the first one, like a behavior that the guy must have like a part of his own, the "don't be" is like a thing that he may achieve.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidWallace! Fixed. Thanks, StoneyB, Ruakh, Apprentive, for the interesting comments!

Comment: @CopperKettle Just responding to your comment/question in my (now deleted) post here. I think you can probably still see it! *BE* is called a copula verb mainly because it has no real meaning and takes a complement which is a PC describing the subject. However, it is classified as an auxiliary not because of any complements that it takes or doesn't take in different situations but because of the special NICE properties that it shows. (i.e. its role in negation, inversion, emphasis and code). While *copula* is an important term describing this verb, *auxiliary* describes ...

Comment: @CopperKettle ... a subcategory of the word category *verb* in the same kind of way that *pronoun* may indicate a subcategory of the class *noun* [ depending on your grammar ]. You might be wondering why I deleted my post, the reason has to do with subjunctives, imperatives and some weird stuff that happens in conditionals. This plus the fact that the analysis everywhere on this seems to be a bit thin - including CaGEL! And I'm no longer sure what I think - or can usefully say ... :)

Comment: @CopperKettle ... If you're interested in NICE properties and auxiliaries, I did [a wee post here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/209132/is-helper-verb-old-school/209189#209189) and another [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/185713/does-using-did-to-form-the-past-tense-make-a-difference/185915#185915). They aren't all that good but I don't know of any others on SE ...

Comment: @Araucaria - thank you for being so NICE! (0: Thanks for the links! I'll surely read up on this!