# Is “didn’t be” an acceptable usage?

Tags: past-tense

One of my friends once said “At least you didn’t be diplomatic.”. It somehow felt a little unsettling. Is “didn’t be” acceptable? Is it grammatically correct?

Comment: It might be intended as a substitute for "You at least needn't be diplomatic" or a shorter version of "You at least didn't need to be diplomatic".

Comment: No, it isn't correct. Maybe a slip of the tongue for "didn't try to be diplomatic".

Comment: To add to what @KateBunting has said, he could have said "weren't diplomatic."

Comment: It's unusual, but I don't agree that it's ungrammatical.

Comment: “Weren’t diplomatic” is what I thought it should’ve been. But I also wanted to know if it was acceptable to use it.

Comment: I would think your friend was trying to say that you weren't undiplomatic.

Comment: @Xanne nah, she was saying that I wasn't being diplomatic. :)

Comment: Related: [Conditional: “are not” vs. “don't be”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/44100)

Comment: @sumelic Thank you! Don't have enough rep to upvote the comment. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most verbs in English form the negative in a strange way:

> You jumped -> you didn't jump
>   You saw -> you didn't see

using the infinitive form ("jump", "see") and an auxiliary verb ("do", for example).

But a few special verbs (auxiliary verbs) form their negative in a different way by adding "not"

> You were -> you were not = you weren't
>   You should -> you should not = you shouldn't

instead of

> You were -> *you didn't be
>   You should -> *you didn't should

Perhaps if you read very old things, you find that even normal verbs used to do it this way

> You jumped -> you jumped not
>   She loves me -> she loves me not